# DOMPDF Rendering Speed and Server Requirements

Tags: php, dompdf

I've had great success with rendering PDFS with this library. I'm currently rendering PDFs which contain 4 pages of images at a size of 2056x2056, scaled down to fit on the page. This is to provide better resolution from the 72dpi base images.

These pdfs take about 1.5 minutes to render though. If I need to add a few sets of these, I quickly time the virtual private server I'm on out, locking up all it's resources for that time frame.

We are thinking of moving to a better server, which brings me to my question. How much of a performance gain would I see by moving to an upgraded server with more ram and a faster processor? Is there anything specific I should look for in a server to speed up rendering? Quad Core, etc?

Thanks

Comment: we do 2.5, 4 page pdfs with dompdf per second, so yours seem a little slow. however TCPDF renders around 4 times faster. 4 core 4 times faster than 1 core, we use 8 core, and make sure all 8 are being used 100%, buy running 8 copies of the script.

Comment: FYI, this question is also being discussed on the [dompdf support forum](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/dompdf/EYWiRaDmbjs/discussion)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but I think it's worth pointing out ...

Assuming you currently are using DOMPDF with the ROSPDF support (as opposed to PDFLIB, which costs $$$), I'd say you could **definitely** improve performance simply by using a better tool to scale the images. By this I mean:

> Try using a tool like Imagemagick (which has PHP bindings) to convert
>   the images to a PDF as your first step, then combine the resulting
>   PDFs using DOMPDF.

Unless you have bottomless pockets -- or someone else is paying (**yippie!**) -- a solution like Imagemagick (whose libs are written in C) should be considered before blowing money on a beefed-up box to handle image processing with PHP.